# in UWP is there a way to switch between designs if the width is bigger than the Height?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I want to have two different designs and make the application choose one depending on the ratio between the height and the width.
I can only find AdaptiveTriggers which take a static MinWindowWidth or MinWindowHeight .but what I need is no matter how big or small the screen is if the height is bigger than the width go with the first design and if the width is bigger go with the second design.

Comment: when do you want it to switch during runtime or before the page loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom state triggers, like [@dotMorten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1702326/dotmorten) in [WindowsStateTriggers](https://github.com/dotMorten/WindowsStateTriggers)

I have created a trigger for you, which listens on the `Window.Current.SizeChanged` event and updated the trigger's state for you. The `WeakEventListener` class is from the [WindowsStateTriggers](https://github.com/dotMorten/WindowsStateTriggers) repo.

```
public class WindowShapeTrigger : StateTriggerBase
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty WindowShapeTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "WindowShapeType", typeof(WindowShapeType), typeof(WindowShapeTrigger), new PropertyMetadata(WindowShapeType.Narrow, OnWindowShapeTypeChanged));

    private static void OnWindowShapeTypeChanged(DependencyObject s, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = (WindowShapeTrigger)s;
        if (!Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
        {
            var rect = Window.Current.Bounds;
            obj.UpdateTrigger(new Size(rect.Width, rect.Height));
        }
    }

    public WindowShapeType WindowShapeType
    {
        get { return (WindowShapeType)GetValue(WindowShapeTypeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(WindowShapeTypeProperty, value); }
    }

    public WindowShapeTrigger()
    {
        if (!Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
        {
            var weakEvent = new WeakEventListener<WindowShapeTrigger, object, WindowSizeChangedEventArgs>(this)
            {
                OnEventAction = (instance, source, eventArgs) => WindowShapeTrigger_SizeChanged(source, eventArgs),
                OnDetachAction = (instance, weakEventListener) => Window.Current.SizeChanged -= weakEventListener.OnEvent
            };
            Window.Current.SizeChanged += weakEvent.OnEvent;
        }
    }

    private void WindowShapeTrigger_SizeChanged(object source, WindowSizeChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        UpdateTrigger(eventArgs.Size);
    }

    private void UpdateTrigger(Size bounds)
    {
        if (WindowShapeType == WindowShapeType.Wide && bounds.Width >= bounds.Height)
        {
            base.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (WindowShapeType == WindowShapeType.Wide && bounds.Width < bounds.Height)
        {
            base.SetActive(false);
        }

        if (WindowShapeType == WindowShapeType.Narrow && bounds.Width <= bounds.Height)
        {
            base.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (WindowShapeType == WindowShapeType.Narrow && bounds.Width > bounds.Height)
        {
            base.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}

public enum WindowShapeType
{
    Narrow,
    Wide
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup >
            <VisualState x:Name="wide">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <local:WindowShapeTrigger WindowShapeType="Wide" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="Rectangle.Fill" Value="Green" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="narrow">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <local:WindowShapeTrigger WindowShapeType="Narrow" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="Rectangle.Fill" Value="Red" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Rectangle Height="200" Width="100" x:Name="Rectangle"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: thank you very much after a few minor adjustments to make it fit the project it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

This snippet might help you:

```
public MainPage()
{            
   if (Window.Current.Bounds.Width<Window.Current.Bounds.Height)
        {
          InitializeComponent(new Uri("ms-appx:///MainPageNewDesign.xaml", UriKind.Absolute));   
        }
        else
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
}
```

Inside default MainPage you can override constructor and load page with another design if height is larger than width